# While comparing a[j]=42 , I am getting message "cannot from convert int to boolean"

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have this small part of a code. When I compare array `a[j] != 42`, it works like a charm. But if I tweak it to `a[j] = 42` , it says:

> cannot convert from 'int' to 'boolean'

What wrong I am doing?

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
    a[i] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    int j = 0;
    do {       
        if (a[j] = 42)
            System.out.println(a[j]);
            else {
                flag=0;break;
            }
        j++;
    } while (flag == 1);
}
```

Comment: @intboolstring do you really need that?

Comment: @Stultuske.  My bad.  I miss understood the part of the code you were asking about.  Never mind.

Comment: looks like you should use == (compare) instead of = (assign); try a[j]==42

Answer (score 4):

`a[j]!=42` is a comparison. `a[j]=42` on the other hand, is an assignment of the value.

The correct way to compare them is: `a[j] == 42`

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers already mention `a[j]=42` is an assignment. What you want it to compare two values. I want to include a little bit more information to what exactly is going on here.

*Explanation:* What your code does is assign 42 to `a[j]`. `a[j]` would be contain / be equal to 42 after that line. The assignment itself is fine.

But the compiler expects a boolean expression inside its `if (...)` to determine wether it should enter the following code block or the one of the `else`-branch. The assignment operator `=` in Java returns the assigned value. Therefore the statement `a[j]=42` returns 42 which the compiler then wants to get a boolean value from, which it cannot since it `cannot convert from int to boolean`.

*Solution:* Use the `==` operator instead which does not assign at but compares the two values and returns a `boolean` wether or not the two are identical: `if (a[j] == 42)`

Answer (score 0):

You must use == for comparing:
if (a[j] == 42)

Answer (score 0):

`if(a[j]=42)`

This is equivalent to:

```
a[j] = 42
if(a[j]) {
}
```

Now, since you are checking `42` as boolean, you get the error: `cannot covert from 'int' to 'boolean'`

As other answers suggest, you need `==` for comparison.